# Clicking link should expire the session

Tags: php, session

I have a link like `<a href="some link">Click</a> .` Now,On clicking this link should made the session to expire..ie.,using `session_destroy().`

Answer (score 4):

It is strongly advisable to avoid this type of operations in order to avoid CSRF attacks.

For example you will create a link that points to `http://site.come/logout`
Then, I grab the url and make an image with its source set to the mentioned url.

```
<img src="http://site.come/logout"/>
```

Now on any other webpage when a user from you site will be exposed to this image he will be automatically logged out from your system.

I would suggest using POST.

```
<input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout"/>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
        session_destroy(); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: That can easily be avoided by adding a unique ID tied to the session to the logout action (ie /user/logout/unique-id), you don't need a POST action.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!--in the index.php page-->

<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>


<!--in the logout.php page-->

<?php
session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
header("location:http://localhost/moon/index.php"); 
//to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
exit();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code.

Suppose you have page session_expr.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['expire'])){
session_start();
session_destroy();
}

?>
<a href="session_expr.php?expire">Destroy session</a>
```

With this you are sending `expire` with `GET` method to the same page on clicking on the link. Once you have `expire` in `GET variable` the PHP code will execute with `session_destroy()` function.